# How to get the Query String variable in ASP.NET and pass it as an Sql parameter?

Tags: asp.net, query-string, sqlparameter

```
string userid = Request.QueryString[0].ToString();
string Qid = Request.QueryString[1].ToString();
string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString.ToString();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
con.Open();

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("qualification", con);
com.Parameters.Add("@proctype",SqlDbType.Int).Value = 4;
com.Parameters.Add("@Qid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Qid;
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   drpqualification.SelectedItem.Text = reader["Qualification"].ToString();
   txtSubjects.Text = reader["Subject"].ToString();
   txtmarksobt.Text = reader["MarksObtained"].ToString();
   txtgrade.Text = reader["Percentage"].ToString();
   txtboard.Text = reader["BoardUniversity"].ToString();
}
reader.Close();
con.Close();
}
```

- and  here the URL:http://localhost:35689/Academic_info.aspx?userid=94&Qid=14
  i want to get the Qid only and pass it as Sql Parameter*

Comment: Are you facing any error? If so, provide that details.

Comment: i want to get the"Qid" value  only which is there in URL but by using Request.QueryString["Qid"].tostring() it returns the complete string.

Comment: To fetch the query string, just use `Request.QueryString["Qid"]`. You don't need to `.ToString()` it.

Comment: it doesn't works as it returns the complete string not the actual value of Qid

Comment: It shouldn't. However, as a temporary solution, you can do `Request.QueryString["Qid"].Replace("Qid=",String.Empty)`

Comment: it doesn't work :( , but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should add values to parameters as below -

```
    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;

    // Use AddWithValue to assign Demographics. 
    // SQL Server will implicitly convert strings into XML.
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demographics", demoXml);
```

Check this URL - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

And to fetch the query string, just use `Request.QueryString["Qid"]`. You don't need to `.ToString()` it.